# Ansible, get n-th item from list after splitting string

Tags: ansible

I'm having a little trouble.

Let's say I have `variable_a` which is a list like this: `["item1", "item2", "item3"]`

I know I can reference the first or n-th item of a list type variable like this: `variable_a[0]`

However, let's say the variable is more complicated, and `variable_b` looks like this:

```
[
        [
            "BOOT path-list      : flash:c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-7.E7.bin"
        ],
        [
            "BOOT path-list      : flash:c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-7.E7.bin",
            "Config file         : flash:/config.text",
            "Private Config file : flash:/private-config.text",
            "Enable Break        : yes",
            "Manual Boot         : no",
            "Allow Dev Key         : yes",
            "HELPER path-list    : ",
            "Auto upgrade        : yes",
            "Auto upgrade path   : ",
            "Boot optimization   : disabled",
            "NVRAM/Config file",
            "      buffer size:   524288",
            "Timeout for Config",
            "          Download:    0 seconds",
            "Config Download ",
            "       via DHCP:       disabled (next boot: disabled)"
        ]
    ]
```

I know this is a list of lists. What I want to do is extract the filename configured in the `BOOT path-list`.

I've come up with something like this which gets me most of the way there:

```
- name: DEBUG OUTPUT
  debug:
    var: variable_b.stdout_lines | flatten | first | trim | regex_replace('\s+', '') | split(':')
```

Output:

```
"variable_b.stdout_lines | flatten | first | trim | regex_replace('\\s+', '') | split(':')": [
    "BOOTpath-list",
    "flash",
    "c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-7.E7.bin"
]
```

Great, now I want to reference index #2, I try something like this: `variable_b.stdout_lines | flatten | first | trim | regex_replace('\s+', '') | split(':')[2]`

However, I get the error:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected
> token 'end of print statement', got '['. String:
> {{variable_b.stdout_lines | flatten | first | trim |
> regex_replace('\\s+', '') | split(':')[2]}}. expected token 'end of
> print statement', got '['"}

How can I reference the n-th item of the output of the `split` function? I'm sure the secret here applies to multiple filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just parenthesize the entire expression, so that you have `(...complex expression...)[2]`. E.g.:

```
- name: DEBUG OUTPUT
  debug:
    msg: >-
      {{
        (
          variable_b.stdout_lines |
          flatten |
          first |
          trim |
          regex_replace('\s+', '') | split(':')
        )[2]
      }}
```

This produces:

```
TASK [DEBUG OUTPUT] *************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-7.E7.bin"
}
```

I'm using `msg` instead of `var` here because the output is a little more brief.

Comment: Thought I had tried that, because that is kind of a standard method. But apparently, I did not. :)  It works!